# Determine the number of kernels in OpenCL program

Tags: c++, opencl

How can I determine the number of kernels in a program in OpenCL with C++? I tried `clGetProgramInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_NUM_KERNELS` even with `clFinish` inbetween this and `clCreateProgramWithSource` but it always tells me 0 kernels. What seems to work, is to call `clCreateKernelsInProgram(OCL_program, N, kernels, &numKernels);` with `N` being set arbitrarily high, but is that the way to go?

I just started with OpenCL and I couldn't find anything to that end...

Let me know, if you need additional code, but building the program and creating a kernel works, so I think, everything should be in order here...

Answer (score 0):

I think your first idea was the way to go using clGetProgramInfo. The documentation here https://man.opencl.org/clGetProgramInfo.html isn't clear on what you should expect the result to be returned into, so I suggest you try something like this to get the variable size. I use C not C++, so I use the standard integers, but you may have to do something different in C++. (Not Tested)

```
uint??_t num_kernels;
size_t sizeofnumkernels;
cl_int cl_ret = clGetProgramInfo(myprogram, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_KERNELS,
                        (size_t)(sizeof(num_kernels)),
                        (void *)&num_kernels,
                        &sizeofnumkernels);
if (sizeof(num_kernels) != sizeofnumkernels) {
  printf("Invalid size for num_kernels. %li expected.\n");
}
```